# Django validate data when updating model with primary key

Tags: django

I am having trouble with updating fields of a model instance. The model is as follows:

```
class commonInfo(models.Model):
    mothers_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    data_collector = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Essentially, I just want to do this, but it won't work because `commonInfo` has a user defined primary key

```
commonInfo_form(request.POST or None).is_valid()
```

Since I am updating, I am overriding `date` and `data_collector`, but not `mothers_id`. So I would want to do something like this, but this specific code is not working

```
obj = commonInfo.objects.get(pk=commonInfo_id)
form = commonInfo_form(request.POST)
date = form.cleaned_data['data_collector'] #this line is not working
data_collector = form.cleaned_data['data_collector'] #this line is not working
obj.update(**{'date':date, 'data_collector':data_collector})
```

any ideas? I feel like it is just those two lines that I need to fix. Or if there is a more pythonic way or built method in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just validate with `isinstance`. so like,

```
if isinstance(request.POST['date'], datetime.date) and isinstance(request.POST['data_collector'], str):
    # you might have to use getattr for request.POST here, I'm not sure
    # and request.POST['date'] would have to be converted from a string to datetime.date I think
    date = request.POST['date']
    data_collector = request.POST['data_collector']
    obj.update(**{'date':date, 'data_collector':data_collector})
```

Answer (score 0):

The process for adding a record from a form is different from updating an existing instance. All you need to do differently is indicate which instance to bind the form to when you create it, ex:

```
obj = commonInfo.objects.get(pk=commonInfo_id)
form = commonInfo_form(request.POST, instance=obj)
```

Comment: That took care of the primary_key issue, but now it is saying that the date is invalid, even if I don't change it. How is that possible?

Comment: the django docs say to use this format ```'%b %d, %Y'``` when the date is Jan. 19, 2015. But how would I manually change that in request.POST?

Comment: Are you using a ModelForm to collect this data?

Comment: @TylerManthie815 You can specify the date format(s) to accept by setting input_formats for the date field in your form definition code. See here for details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#datefield